# How To use SlideMenu in left and Right position android?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, slidingmenu

I use [Slidemenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and Sherlok library to use *Slide Menu* in my code.. I wrote two positions and opens.

```
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);


        menu2=new SlidingMenu(getApplicationContext());
        menu2.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        menu2.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu2.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu2.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu2.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu2.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu2.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu2.setMenu(R.layout.activity_rightmenu);
```

now when use touch and open position.not Work Ovelay.

How I do resolve these [problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzzt7.png)?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? If you want to slide left and right, then you don't need to create another `menu2` instance. Just use: `setMenu()`, and `setSecondaryMenu()`.

Comment: its not work for me.because right posotion not work and setSecondaryMenu() worked for left position.

Comment: You should change the mode also: `setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT)`

Comment: thanks..its work Perfrect...Now How to Overlay when position is changed ?